# Checking Flash player version using Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

Is it possible to check the version of the Flash Player installed in a browser using Javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check an example [here](http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/11/20/detecting-flash-player-version-with-javascript/).

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice, lightweight [JavaScript Flash Detection Library](http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html), which is smaller and more convenient than using *SWFObject*. You should consider it, if you only want to check if Flash is installed, what version of Flash Player is installed etc., but you're using different method of playing `FLV` movies.

*SWFObject* should be considered **only**, if you're also using it for playing Flash movies. For just checking, if Flash is installed or what version of Flash player is installed, it is *to heavy*, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at swfobject2: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/