# Detect Flash version using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash

How can I detect which Flash version a browser is using with JavaScript?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: [Adobe Flash Detection Kit](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/download/detection_kit/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check flash player version using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652480/how-to-check-flash-player-version-using-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a nice, lightweight [JavaScript Flash Detection Library](http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html), which is smaller and more convenient than using *SWFObject*. You should consider it, if you only want to check if Flash is installed, but you're using different method of playing `FLV` movies.

*SWFObject* should be considered **only**, if you're also using it for playing Flash movies. For just checking, if Flash is installed, it is *to heavy* in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of going on in [JavaScript Flash Detection Library](http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html), but it seems it can be simplified to something like this:

```
getFlashVer: function () {
    var activeXObj, plugins, plugin, result;

    if (navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins.length > 0) {
        plugins = navigator.plugins;
        for (var i = 0; i < plugins.length && !result; i++) {
            plugin = plugins[i];
            if (plugin.name.indexOf("Shockwave Flash") > -1) {
                result = plugin.description.split("Shockwave Flash ")[1];
            }
        }
    } else {
        plugin = "ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash";
        try {
            activeXObj = new ActiveXObject(plugin + ".7"), result = activeXObj.GetVariable("$version")
        } catch (e) {}

        if (!result) try {
            activeXObj = new ActiveXObject(plugin + ".6"), result = "WIN 6,0,21,0", activeXObj.AllowScriptAccess = "always", result = activeXObj.GetVariable("$version")
        } catch (e) {}

        if (!result) try {
            activeXObj = new ActiveXObject(plugin), result = activeXObj.GetVariable("$version")
        } catch (e) {}

        result && (result = result.split(" ")[1].split(","), result = result[0] + "." + result[1] + " r" + result[2])
    }
    return result ? result : "-";
}
```