# Detecting Flash version from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash

I've seen two answers:

1. Adobe Flash Detection Kit -
   [Detect Flash version using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834980/javascript-detect-flash-version)
2. JavaScript routines only:
   http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/11/20/detecting-flash-player-version-with-javascript/

Simple questions:

1. are the detection algorithms, described above, identical and if not - which way is better?
2. Will they work the same for desktop *and* mobile browsers (both
   iPhone/iPad and Android)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods are not identical but I would recommend using the Adobe provided one since it is more likely to remain functional in future updates to the Flash Player.

Alternatively, you could use SWFObject as recommended by the posters in this thread - [Cross Browser Flash Detection in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159261/cross-browser-flash-detection-in-javascript)

And not worry about the implementation :)

There is no reason that any of these scripts will not run in Safari on the iPad/iPhone or other browsers on Android devices.

Comment: does it react properly when there is no flash at all?