# How to display Flash version in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript code shown below for displaying Browser plugins for Flash Version.

Code is:

```
<script>
txt=navigator.Flash;
document.getElementById("flash").innerHTML = navigator.Flash;
</script>
```

But this code output is displaying

```
undefined
```

I want the version number of flash player to be displayed.

I have no idea how to go ahead. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652480/how-to-check-flash-player-version-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [here](http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/11/20/detecting-flash-player-version-with-javascript/)

Source: [Checking Flash player version using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652480/how-to-check-flash-player-version-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Use swfobject.  With it you can get the flash player version of the user viewing it see http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/